# Api/library for html to mobi/epub conversion

Tags: java, javascript, perl, epub

I am looking forward to an api that can convert html to mobi/epub format and can do a job really well.

My preference is JavaScript but any suggestions for java/perl or some other language api (which does a good job) are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use [EBook::Tools](http://search.cpan.org/dist/EBook-Tools/) CPAN package. It supports epub format for both encoding/decoding.